# Javascript variables and DOM Selectors

Tags: javascript

I have a question about DOM selectors.

Is there a performance difference between;

This code:

```
if (document.getElementById("post-dropdown-menu-" + postID) && document.getElementById("post-dropdown-menu-" + postID).style.display != "none") {
            document.getElementById("post-dropdown-menu-" + postID).fadeOut(200);
            return false;
}
```

And this code:

```
var neededElement = document.getElementById("post-dropdown-menu-" + postID);

if (neededElement && neededElement.style.display != "none") {
            neededElement.fadeOut(200);
            return false;
}
```

I really want to know if browser or javascript doing DOM Select proc. again if element already used in a function.

Comment: Yes. There is no need to query the document twice for the same selector. However since it is an ID selector the performance difference will be extremely small though

Comment: @charlietfl 3 times ;p

Comment: "*Is there a performance difference*" Yes, there would be. However, it's exceptionally unlikely for the difference to be measurable, much less noticeable. So, the question is both "Yes" and "No", depending on what you mean by your question. Also: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the **second** one is **faster** because you only use query selector once which mean less processing.

and here is a test score using JSBench.

[image]

Note that the effect will never be noticed except if you are using this inside a loop or so.